# rowsum across specific columns using dplyr's start_with

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, purrr, rowsum

I am trying to make aggregates for some columns in my dataset. I took great pains to make the data organized, so I want to use the column names to add across my scales, rather than the index.

Here's my data:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(name = c("Ash", "Ashley", "Ashton"),
               hc_1 = c(1, 2, 3),
               hc_2 = c(2, 2, 2),
               ur_1 = c(1, 5, 5),
               ur_2 = c(3, 4, 3))
```

I want to make a new column that is the aggregate of the hc values only:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(name = c("Ash", "Ashley", "Ashton"),
               hc_1 = c(1, 2, 3),
               hc_2 = c(2, 2, 2),
               ur_1 = c(1, 5, 5),
               ur_2 = c(3, 4, 3),
               hc_agg = c(3, 4, 5))
```

I've tried this code but receive an error:

```
data %>% mutate(hc_agg = pmap_dbl(select(., starts_with("hc"))), ~rowsum)

Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default
```

Again, I know that I could use the index, but this dataset may have the variables shift around. I'd rather use the column names to keep it safer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just `dplyr`, you can do:

```
data %>%
 mutate(hc_agg = rowSums(select(., starts_with("hc"))))

  name    hc_1  hc_2  ur_1  ur_2 hc_agg
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Ash        1     2     1     3      3
2 Ashley     2     2     5     4      4
3 Ashton     3     2     5     3      5
```

Comment: thanks! That was so quick and helpful! It won't let me accept the answer yet, but in 10 minutes I will.

Answer (score 1):

One way is

```
data %>% 
    nest(starts_with("hc"), .key = "hc") %>% 
    mutate(hc_agg = map(hc, sum)) %>% 
    unnest

name    ur_1    ur_2    hc_agg  hc_1    hc_2
<chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
Ash     1       3       3       1       2
Ashley  5       4       4       2       2
Ashton  5       3       5       3       2
```